# How Do I Get My Gallery (3 Pictures) To Center?

Tags: html

I feel like I'm really close to get it but I'm not sure what I should do exactly. How can I get this gallery to be centered, rather than pushed to the right?

```html
<figure class="wp-block-gallery columns-3 is-cropped"><ul class="blocks-gallery-grid"><li class="blocks-gallery-item"><figure><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example1-768x1024.jpg" alt="example" data-id="1343" data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example1.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example1/" class="wp-image-1343"/></figure></li><li class="blocks-gallery-item"><figure><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example2-576x1024.jpg" alt="example" data-id="1319" data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example2.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example2/" class="wp-image-1319"/></figure></li><li class="blocks-gallery-item"><figure><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example3-768x1024.jpg" alt="example" data-id="1330" data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example3.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example3/" class="wp-image-1330"/></figure></li></ul></figure>
```

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Please check my answer without bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below style **without using the bootstrap.**

```
 ul {
        list-style-type: none;  

   }
   img{
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 50%;
   }
```

```css
 ul {
            list-style-type: none;  

       }
       img{
          display: block;
          margin:0 auto;
          width: 50%;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Estudo Navbar</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <figure class="wp-block-gallery columns-3 is-cropped">
    <ul class="blocks-gallery-grid">
      <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80" alt="example" data-id="1343" 
          data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example1.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example1/" class="wp-image-1343"/>
        </figure>
     </li>
        
     <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
          <figure><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80" alt="example" data-id="1319" 
               data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example2.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example2/" class="wp-image-1319"/>
          </figure>
     </li>
     
     <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
          <figure><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80" alt="example" data-id="1330" 
               data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example3.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example3/" class="wp-image-1330"/>
          </figure>
     </li>
   </ul>
</figure>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I do it for it to be horizontal instead of vertical? Or is it just the way it looks on this screen right now maybe?

Comment: @newwebsitecreator, you can add display:flex to the ul class. It will show as horizontal. If you want my suggestion, i would prefer them to be in horizontal on large screen and stack them on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bootstrap class called **d-flex** which displays your container as a dynamic grid system, followed  by **just-content-center** and **align-items-center** that arranges your container to the center of the page.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <figure class="wp-block-gallery columns-3 is-cropped">
    <ul class="blocks-gallery-grid">
      <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
        <figure><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example1-768x1024.jpg" alt="example" data-id="1343" data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example1.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example1/" class="wp-image-1343" /></figure>
      </li>
      <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
        <figure><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example2-576x1024.jpg" alt="example" data-id="1319" data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example2.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example2/" class="wp-image-1319" /></figure>
      </li>
      <li class="blocks-gallery-item">
        <figure><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example3-768x1024.jpg" alt="example" data-id="1330" data-full-url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example3.jpg" data-link="https://example.com/example3/" class="wp-image-1330" /></figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @newwebsitecreator, if you find this answer helpful, please mark it as "Answer".

Comment: @newwebsitecreator, I am glad it helped you :)